# Change Asterisk chan_mobile packets size

Tags: asterisk, sip, rtp

When call is made between two chan_mobile channels, all works fine.
But not when call is established between SIP and chan_mobile (through simple bridge).


SIP -> mobile is clear and fine with controllable packet size in sip.conf
Reverse direction voice going in too small packets causing near 180 kbits/s and loosing packets because of out of order on SIP phone side (if not enabled permissive mode on RTP).


So question is how to increase packets size originated by chan_mobile and going to SIP?

Setting like

```
allow=ulaw:100
```

not works in chan_mobile.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chan mobile to chan_sip connection is via sln internal bridge ALWAYS.

You can control only outgoing packets(from your server sip to remote sip) by set

```
allow=g729:20
```

Or similar form. Please note, that codec should support length of packet you asking.

You have no any way control other side, so no way control inbound direction.

For more info see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/RTP+Packetization

Comment: Thank you. But incoming SIP packets really controlled by changing "allow=ulaw:100" (confirmed by wireshark monitoring). I suspect it is because of "autoframing=yes". But I can't really control "server sip to remote sip" packets size.

Comment: There is no other answer. All other is debug. I can state that outbound path CONTROLLED by that directive. Maybe you just use other trunk or something. It is not programming question, you have debug yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I trust you experience. Seems you are absolutely right. I will debug in this direction.